# Bandwidth Aggregation

Tags: isp

I have two ILL connections of 2 Mbps from different ISP's. How could I merge both the connections to get the merged bandwidth. Also I want to give the single range IP address like : 192.168.x.x to my entire network with uniform accessibility for all.

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You can use a WAN link balancer to do the job. [Elfiq](http://www.elfiq.com/), [Barracuda](http://www.barracudanetworks.com/ns/products/link_overview.php), [Peplink](http://www.peplink.com/), Fortigate, etc. all offer devices that could help aggregate WAN traffic and allow you to apply specific policies and leverage failover if there's an outage a link.

Also see: [Multi-WAN bonding across different media](https://serverfault.com/questions/401661/multi-wan-bonding-across-different-media/401683#401683) or [Two identical fiber optic broadband lines working as one](https://serverfault.com/questions/426645/two-identical-fiber-optic-broadband-lines-working-as-one/426720#426720)