# Internet connection redundancy with 2 ISP

Tags: isp, redundancy

Setup is 
1. One Linux server running web server and ftp server.
2. Two ISP which provided a range of public IP address 
3. From the client(browser) side we can set only one of IP/domain name as target for web/ftp request. (Can not change the destination server )

What is the configuration required to have redundant net connection and access to server. If one ISP is down we should able to reach server by other ISP link
Right now we are not looking at DNS way of switching between active ISP links.
Is there any other way of achieving this by using router or something.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

DNS-based solutions are one solution to this problem, but they are subject to ISPs that ignore TTLs and cache your DNS responses for improperly large periods, thus torpedoing your failover.

You can arrange for an IP range to be properly highly-available over multiple links to independent ISPs, but it's painful, expensive, and requires an expert network admin.  In essence, you get some PI IPv4 space and an ASN, plus a professional-grade router, hook up to ISPs that support BGP, and advertise your own addresses to the internet-at-large.

If any of the above confuses you, **you should not attempt to do this**; it is *much* easier and cheaper to work with your existing ISP to arrange redundantly-routed connections to your premises.  Any large ISP **will** be doing BGP with their peers, so their connections to the internet are unlikely to fail completely (if they do, you should certainly get a new ISP).  They will also have multiple local POPs, and should be able to arrange for the links to your premises to route through completely disparate infrastructures.

One notable advantage to taking this path is that the ISP will usually give you a big discount on the second link, since it only ever has to carry traffic when the first one's down.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Buy a *link balancer* capable of inbound and outbound load balancing.

The [product line from Elfiq](http://elfiq.com/products) is particularly good at this and is my choice for ISP redundancy solutions.

Also see: [Multiple broadband providers for internal web servers](https://serverfault.com/questions/477694/multiple-broadband-providers-for-internal-web-servers/477701#477701)

Comment: I can see how those do an elegant job of making highly-available *outbound* connections, but do they also provide a solution for *inbound* ones?  I apologise if I'm missing something.

Comment: @MadHatter Sure: See http://serverfault.com/questions/477694/multiple-broadband-providers-for-internal-web-servers/477701#477701

Comment: Ah, OK, so it's DNS-based failover in a box.  Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: They don't support IPv6 at the moment though. It is on their roadmap but it might be a good idea to get commitment from them on when they deliver. You're going to need it at some point, which will probably be sooner than you expect:)